# SQLite returns Unicode buffer that cannot be converted to usable strings

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm reading in records from a sqlite3 database. 
The data is stored as TEXT in the database, however I'm getting buffers back (which are in Unicode and nothing I can find seems to convert them into useable text (Unicode or not))

To make it work I have to CAST to a TEXT in the SQL query.

What point am I missing?

As an example:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('D:\\test.db' )
cur = con.cursor()


print "Before CAST"
cur.execute('SELECT Type FROM \"Internet Explorer History\" ')
row = cur.fetchone()

print row
print row[0]
print type(row[0])
print str(row[0])
print str(row[0]).encode('utf-8')

print "----------------"

print "After CAST"
cur.execute('SELECT CAST( Type as TEXT) FROM \"Internet Explorer History\" ')
row = cur.fetchone()

print row
print row[0]
print type(row[0])
print str(row[0])
print str(row[0]).encode('utf-8')
```

This gives the following output:

```
Before CAST
(<read-write buffer ptr 0x0276A890, size 24 at 0x0276A870>,)
C a c h e  R e c o r d 
<type 'buffer'>
C a c h e  R e c o r d 
C a c h e  R e c o r d 
----------------
After CAST
(u'Cache Record',)
Cache Record
<type 'unicode'>
Cache Record
Cache Record
```

Note: spaces between letters of 'Cache Record' before the CAST are nulls.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try this with the SQLite command line tool? What is the result?

Comment: It returns the correct string ('Cache Record')

Comment: With and without `CAST`?

Comment: what if you print `bytes(row[0])`  and or `repr(row[0])` or `[ord(c) for c in row[0]]`

Comment: Please show the output of `SELECT typeof(Type), quote(Type) FROM "Internet Explorer History"`.

Comment: hmmm, in SQLITE the type comes back as a blob, yet the schema is text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
print str(row[0]).decode('utf-16le')
```

Comment: @cymro, I'm not all that familiar with sqlite but the documentation says it stores all text in the same format depending on the database setup. Obviously your database is setup for utf-16le. By casting it to TEXT the SQL driver probably did the conversion for you. See http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 0):

How data is inserted into your `"Internet Explorer History"` table? My bet is that it's being inserted as a binary object (e.g. Python type buffer), so SQLite returns it as a blob rather than text.

Try inserting proper unicode objects then perform the same query and check its output.